# Object doesn't support this action in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to trigger a calendar event by custom event. It's working fine in Chrome and Safari not in IE11.

```
self.openCalendar = function() {
    var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    event.initCustomEvent("submit", true, true);
    document.getElementById('MDC_' + self.control.uniqueId).dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: `this action`, what action? `It's not working`, define `not working`. Any errors in the console? If yes, what errors?

Comment: which line does not work?

Comment: TypeError : Object doesn't support this action

Comment: self.openCalendar = function () {
            var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
            event.initCustomEvent("submit", true, true);
            document.getElementById('MDC_'+self.control.uniqueId).dispatchEvent(event);
        }

Comment: the code has 6 lines. Which line fails?

Comment: getting error in this line .. event not working or trigger   document.getElementById('MDC_'+self.control.uniqueId).dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: Is IE definitely rendering in IE11 mode and not IE9/10 compatibility mode? dispatchEvent wasn't supported in IE9/10. If you hit F12 you can check in the top right if it's displaying the page as IE11 or if it's actually rendering in 9/10 mode.